# I think Ubuntu 12.04 deleted Windows 7

Tags: 12.04, windows-7

When my computer starts up, it goes to a purple screen. I can go to the Ubuntu side just fine, but when I choose Windows 7 it says:

```
error: invalid EFI file path.
press any key to continue...
```

So what is wrong?

yes, the boot repair worked, thank you!

Comment: Did it work recently? If yes - what have you changed? If no - have you installed a new system? Have you installed ubuntu after Windows? Do you have different paritions for your installations?

The Windows 7 EFI is the windows 7 system partition. It seems grub2 is unable to find this partition (Usually a 100 MB partition labeld as system partition).

So basically .... tell us more details about your system

Answer (score 3):

Obviously you need to repair your EFI booting.
It can be happens if:
 1. Was reinstalled system.
 2. Your UEFI partition was broken, formatted, or erratic cleaned.

Exist nice solution for this:

Open your `terminal` and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
```

Press Enter key, and wait for completion. Then type:

```
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Again press Enter key, wait for install completion and program running.

For next steps refer to this links:

[Ubuntu Documentation - Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#Using%20Boot-Repair)
[Boot-Repair project](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/)